# Lookup dates and calculate expiratrion

Tags: vba, excel

I have two data reports where I sort the data in data report 1 and move it to a sheet called "List". To finish off the report I then,

1. Get a date from data report two for every line I have in the sorted list. To do this I have tried to take the action title in column "G" in the sheet "List" and then I search for it in the sheet "Data2" in column "C", then I return the row number and want to save a number there is in the column "G". This number is the days to deadline and can either be a positive or negative number.
2. Take today's date + / - the number and put the modified date and the sheet "Lists" in column "N" to be able to see when every task has deadline.

I can't get other kinds of data in the reports so I have to solve this with some VBA. The code I have tried is this.

```
Sub InsertDate()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim RowNr As Long
    Dim ActionTitle As String
    Dim DaysToExp As Long
    Dim ExpDate As Date
    Dim Found As Range
    Dim FoundRow As Long
    Dim Sign As String
    Dim Days As String
    Dim RowNr2 As Long

    ScreenUpdate = False

    RowNr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    RowNr2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data2").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data2")

    ws1.Range("N1").Value = "Expected start date"

    For i = 2 To RowNr
        ActionTitle = ws1.Range("G" & i).Value

        Set Found = ws2.Range("C1:C" & RowNr2).Find(What:=ActionTitle, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Activate

        FoundRow = ActiveCell.row

        Days = ws2.Range("G" & FoundRow).Value

        If Days = "" Then
            DaysToExp = DaysToExp + 0
        ElseIf Left(Days, 1) = "-" Then
            Sign = "-"
            DaysToExp = Replace(Days, "-", "")
        Else
            Sign = "+"
            DaysToExp = DaysToExp + Days
        End If

        ExpDate = "=TODAY() & Sign & DaysToExp"

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Range("N" & i).Value = ExpDate
    Next i

    ScreenUpdate = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit the subject into something more descriptive, you might get more help that way.

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? Runs into a bug, returns no value, returns wrong values?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. maybe give some input with expected and actual output.... Reading your questions it sounds a bit like you could use the [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) function to do some of the work.

Comment: I am not sure if you can use `.activate` combining with `.find` all you need to do is instead of `FoundRow = activecell.row` you need to use `FoundRow = Found.row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tightened up your code a bit and removed the `.Find` in place of a worksheet function `.Match`. You don't need to parse out the sign of *Days* since you can add a negative number to the date.

```
Sub InsertDate()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RowNr As Long, DaysToExp As Long, FoundRow As Long, RowNr2 As Long
    Dim ActionTitle As String, Sign As String, Days As String
    Dim ExpDate As Date
    Dim Found As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data2")

    RowNr2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws1
        RowNr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("N1").Value = "Expected start date"

        For i = 2 To RowNr
            ActionTitle = ws1.Range("G" & i).Value

            If CBool(Application.CountIf(ws2.Range("C1:C" & RowNr2), ActionTitle)) Then
                FoundRow = Application.Match(ActionTitle, ws2.Range("C1:C" & RowNr2), 0)
                Days = ws2.Range("G" & FoundRow).Value
                ExpDate = Date + Days
                .Range("N" & i).Value = ExpDate
            Else
                Debug.Print "missing " & ActionTitle
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I threw a debug.print in that will report to the VBE's Immediate window if *ActionTitle* cannot be found.

Comment: Thank you a lot Jeeped. It's a much cleaner and better code. :)